# Как пересылать из различных телеграм каналов в один?

Tags: python, telebot, telethon

Как сделать пересыльщик новостей из множества каналов в один? можно ли сделать это с помощью telebot? Если нельзя то как это сделать с помощью telethon?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Справился с этой задачей, все делается очень просто, вот готовый код:

```
from telethon import TelegramClient, events

api_id = "api id"
api_hash = 'hash'
inputo = "сhat_id канала из которого нужно пересылать"
outputo = "сhat_id канала в который нужно пересылать"
perisilaka = TelegramClient('client', api_id, api_hash)
perisilaka.start()

@perisilaka.on(events.NewMessage(inputo))
async def main(event):
    await perisilaka.forward_messages(outputo, event.message)
    

perisilaka.run_until_disconnected()
```

Answer (score 0):

Да, можно сделать пересыльщик новостей из множества телеграм каналов в один используя библиотеку Telebot для Python или Telethon.

С помощью библиотеки Telebot можно создать бота, который будет подписан на нужные вам каналы и пересылать новости в формате сообщений в целевой канал по мере их появления в оригинальных каналах. В Telebot для этого можно использовать методы get_updates() и forward_message(). Однако, Telebot работает только с API Telegram Bot, поэтому если вам нужно получить доступ к полному функционалу, вам нужно будет использовать Telethon.

Comment: Спасибо, начал разбираться потихоньку, по вашему совету выбрал Telethon, оказывается для Telebot требуется обладать правами администратора в канале.